# Error: " Undefined Reference to" - Compile C extension for Python using Anaconda

Tags: python, c, gcc, anaconda

I have the following problem on a 64-bit Windows server:

I have a .c file that declares a Python extension. The .c file compiles to a .o file, using the following command

```
gcc -c chr.c -IC:\Anaconda\include -o chr.o
```

Now, the .o file is created and all is well. But when I try to create the .py file, I get the error response below.

What I understand is that in my c code I call the 'not_doublevector', '__impPy_InitModule4', 'chr' and 'pyvector_to_Carrayptrs' functions.

```
gcc -shared chr.o -LC:\Anaconda\libs -lpython27 -o chr.py

chr.o:chr.c:(.text+0x1a15): undefined reference to `not_doublevector'
chr.o:chr.c:(.text+0x1a35): undefined reference to `not_doublevector'
chr.o:chr.c:(.text+0x1a89): undefined reference to `pyvector_to_Carrayptrs'
chr.o:chr.c:(.text+0x1a99): undefined reference to `pyvector_to_Carrayptrs'
chr.o:chr.c:(.text+0x1aeb): undefined reference to `chr'
chr.o:chr.c:(.text+0x1c3d): undefined reference to `__imp_Py_InitModule4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Have you "officially" installed Anaconda or are you just referring to the libraries. There is some very specific installation and tuning of linear algebra libraries that is done as part of an Anaconda installation? I might recommend installing scipy first if you have not done so already.

Comment: I would also recommend pasting the error directly into your question.

Comment: Hi Joshua, scipy is already installed. The error is referring to functions that I make use of in my c Code. They should however be recognized from the Python.h header, and therefore I don't understand why it won't work. I also tried importing the modules directly in Python, and posted a separate error in another quesiton.

Comment: No I understand that your error relates to C libs not being included properly. I asked about scipy because numpy is essentially a wrapper to these libs and if it installed correctly, then you could be certain that BLAS, et al have been installed correctly. That said, I am certain that your issue is specific to the system being used. 

Unfortunately, my only advice is to dig into the header files themselves and attempt to track down which file is not being properly included.

Comment: You're the man. Will post when I have found the issue.

Comment: Hi Joshua, I was able to fix this problem. The issue was that the functions mentioned above were forward declared in my header files, but the body of the function was declared in a separate source file. I copied the function body into my source file and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem. The issue was that the functions mentioned above were forward declared in my header files, but the body of the function was declared in a separate source file that used these same header files. I copied the function body into my source file and everything worked